# Transform:scale and :nth-child() selector don't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, codepen

I'm currently learning HTML5 / CSS / jQuery. I wanted to make a simple article thumbnails with CSS-based animations. I am using CodePen to easily share these small things. Unfortunately i found out few problems, i don't kno how to solve.

**1. Scale Transform** 
My first problem is that scale transform, which is added to the class .singleArticle doesn't work. It's probably becouse of conflit with some other class, but i cant find it.

```
.singleArticle:hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
   box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   -o-transform: scale(1.2);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

**2. FontAwsome**
Second problem is :nth-child() selector. I would like to learn how it exactly work in practise (that's why i'm using it here). I tried already many things and can't find where the bug is.

```
.singleArticle .cover {
   height: 250px;
   background-size: cover;
   background: #ccc;
   width: 100%;
   color: white;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
}

.singleArticle .cover:nth-child(1) {
   background-image: url("http://www.surfermag.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DecodingStyle_5.jpg");
}

.singleArticle .cover:nth-child(2) {
   background-image: url("http://www.fatbmx.com/uploads4/2014Q1/viki1.jpg");
}
```

**3. Firefox Browser**
All blocks are invisible in firefox. Also can't find any solution.

Can you point, where do i make mistakes, please? Probably the easiest way is just to take a look on codepen, as it's probably not best idea to place whole code here.

```
http://codepen.io/danzawadzki/pen/vymVed
```

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to place code here. But you should try to post a minimal example where your issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work fine.

```css
.singleArticle .cover {
  /* You can just use 'background' */
  background: #ccc url("") center/cover no-repeat;
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
}

/* nth-child selector for .singleArticle, that applies to .cover */

.singleArticle:nth-child(1) .cover {
  background-image: url("http://www.surfermag.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DecodingStyle_5.jpg");
}
.singleArticle:nth-child(2) .cover {
  background-image: url("http://www.fatbmx.com/uploads4/2014Q1/viki1.jpg");
}
.singleArticle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
  /* just extra visual effect */
  transition: box-shadow 300ms, transform 300ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="singleArticle">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
<div class="singleArticle">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost solved all my problems. Selectors are working fine now. I have remaked jquery and created new class responsible for adding and removing opacity:0. But i still have problem with scale transform.*

Comment: Hmm.. funny. If you'd add 'transform: scale(1);' to .singleArticle, as initial state, does this help?

Comment: I have kind of solved it. There was some conflit between slide in animation and hover. I decided to delete first one and looks like scale works fine now. Thanks a lot for you help! Can you also take a look at FontAwsome? I added it near comments and publish date, but its invisible now. I tried on local and on codepen. Both dont work, so probably i make some mistake somewhere.*

Answer (score 1):

For point 2, nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent, so 'n' can be a number, formula, keyword. You can refer https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/ .

For point 3, please remove the opacity: 0 under .singleArticle.

```
.singleArticle {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    width: 430px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, about nth-child() selector i have already solved it. About opacity, i can not do this, because my animation is basing on opacity: 0 and via jquery im adding class .isVisible, which contains opacity 1.